# Is it possible to paste with line breaks (and escaped text) in WebStorm?

Tags: escaping, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I've got some logging that has a SQL query in it:

```
WITH customer_orders AS (\n... id, \"name\",
```

I'm certain in the past I've pasted text like that into WebStorm and gotten a result like:

```
WITH customer_orders AS (
... id, "name",
```

(`...` "just means other stuff here")

Is there a trick to getting WebStorm to recognize escaped characters? It would save me time doing a find/change to make a query that's usable in the db tool. I don't see anything in the Edit menu or Settings that would do this.